# UFt Reporting Layout

Tags: hp-uft, alm

I have automated a web application with UFT using BPT framework in ALM.After execution of END to END scenario, the run report is displaying results at component level. It is not showing different flows that are getting executed.The report is just showing all the components of E2E.So, how can I change the layout of the run result report of UFT so that it displays the flows as well.

Answer (score 0):

UFT by default will group components with in the flow and once you expand your flow you should be able to view the components and steps executed inside components.